# What do you need to know and do when your migrate from a UX practitioner to a UX manager?

Tags: ux-field, jobs, management, team-building

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are various Senior UX Expert job roles and path forward?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18449/what-are-various-senior-ux-expert-job-roles-and-path-forward)

What skill sets, discipline, workflow or/and tools you absolutely required at the beginning of your UX manager career when you've been a UX practitioner working alone for years?

Comment: This is a bit too much of a discussion question to be within the rules of the site. However similar questions have been asked back when the site was in beta (such as http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/what-5-things-must-i-do-to-become-a-well-rounded-progressive-ux-designer-in-my?rq=1), you can see these in the related section on the right --->